# Firebase message (FCM) not work in close app

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This Post is referenced by FCM.
If the application is active state or in background state then all is well it's working fine.
But if you close(Terminate) the application. 
The messages do not come, that I would not do it.
Priority is high in messages.

Messages like :

```
act = msg;
    aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    "chat_id" = 26;
    date = "2016-08-23 08:05:21";
    delay = 300;
    "from_user" = 25;
    "gcm.message_id" = "0:1471939....f965049af";
    id = 898;
    "is_read" = 0;
    msg = sds;
    type = 1;
```

How to make that message come close application?

Comment: are you sending the notification from the firebase console or you are using your own server implementation? The code you have posted is the JSON that you send as the notification?

Comment: i am unable to understand what you want to say

Comment: @GeorgeLBA 
1. Server IMPLEMENTATION
2. YES

Comment: @KartikSinghBhadoriya 
I want to be push notification  when the app is close(push)

Comment: @Northex notification is display in notification window in mobile but didrecevienotifcation method will call after you click on that notification in notification window

Comment: @Northex: Did you declare the service that extends FirebaseMessagingService in your AndroidManifest.xml? and is the onMessageReceived method being called after the application is closed?

Comment: @GeorgeLBA 
I have iOS application

Comment: @NorthEx: did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem. If you send a message from the console, it shows up on "closed" IOS app. If you send via the API it does not. On occasion, the message will appear on the phone after the app is restarted (handled in the same way as if the app were in foreground).

Answer (score 0):

Just ran many tests.  It appears that in order to have the message delivered to a "closed" IOS app, you need to specific priority=high.  With priority unspecified or set to "normal" it will not deliver the notification to a closed app. When the app restarts, it seems the undelivered messages will be sent and handled in the same way as if the app were in the foreground when they were sent originally.